# Rails 4.0.0 - Password on a form won't save into database through either the console or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, console, passwords, save

I am having this issue in Rails when I try to save some form data to my database. I have taken the validation in the model away from the password but it is still not saving for some reason. I am using strong parameters in my controller to take care of the form fields but upon a `render :json => .inspect`, the password is still intact at that point. The error seems to occur when I try to save the data. All non password entries are working, even with validation. I had this exact problem before and was told to delete my `db/development.sqlite3` file in Rails, for which it had worked that time. This time however I have done that several times to no avail.

Below is an example of 3 commands I had run in the rails console as an attempt to manually create an entry. It *seems* to have created a fully populated entry with a password but upon a call to that entry in the database, there is nothing. (Which I have replaced with some text in double stars for your reference).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
2.1.1 :011 > Borrower.new
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+-----+------------+------------+--------                         ----+------------+------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | email | password | nmf | descrip... | amnt_ne... |     amnt_ra... | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    |            |           |       |          |     |            |            |              |            |            |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+-----+------------+------------+--------  ----+------------+------------+
1 row in set
2.1.1 :012 > Borrower.create(first_name:"John", last_name:"Appleseed",     email:"john@gmail.com", password:"johnny", nmf: "Apple seeds", description: "I'm on a mission", amnt_needed: 10000, amnt_raised: 0)
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Borrower Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "borrowers" WHERE LOWER("borrowers"."email") = LOWER('john@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "borrowers" ("amnt_needed", "amnt_raised", "created_at", "description", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "nmf", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["amnt_needed", 10000], ["amnt_raised", 0], ["created_at", Tue, 17 Jun 2014 19:52:23 UTC +00:00], ["description", "I'm on a mission"], ["email", "john@gmail.com"], ["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Appleseed"], ["nmf", "Apple seeds"], ["updated_at", Tue, 17 Jun 2014 19:52:23 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | first_... | last_name | email     | password | nmf       | descri... | amnt_... | amnt_... | create... | update... |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 6  | John      | Appleseed | john@g... | johnny   | Apple ... | I'm on... | 10000    | 0        | 2014-0... | 2014-0... |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set
2.1.1 :013 > Borrower.first
  Borrower Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "borrowers".* FROM "borrowers" ORDER BY "borrowers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--     --------+-----------+-----------+
| id | first_... | last_name | email     | password | nmf       | descri... | amnt_... |    amnt_... | create... | update... |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 6  | John      | Appleseed | john@g... | **THIS IS WHERE THE PASSWORD WOULD HAVE BEEN** | Apple ... | I'm on... | 10000    | 0        | 2014-0... | 2014-0... |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set
```

EDIT 1: On request, I have added more code for Borrower.

**BorrowersController**

```
class BorrowersController < ApplicationController
def create
    # render :text => 'Reached borrowers#create'
    @user = Borrower.new(borrower_params)
    # render json: borrower_params
    if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:notice] = "New borrower was created!"
        if (@user.id == 1) 
            # Since the lenders will not show borrowers properly, the first borrower should me made to be the second.
            @user.id = 2
            # Create a new borrower that serves as a dummy
            Borrower.create(id: 1, first_name: "dummy")
        end
        @lenders_transactions = Transaction.where(borrower_id: params[:id])
        @amnt_raised = 0
        @lenders_transactions.each do |l|
            @amnt_raised += l.amnt
        end
        @user.amnt_raised = @amnt_raised
        @user.save
        redirect_to "/borrowers/" + @user.id.to_s
    else
        flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
        redirect_to "/online_lendings/register"
    end 
end

def show 
    @user = Borrower.find(params[:id])
    @user.amnt_raised = @amnt_raised;
    @lenders = @user.lenders
end

private
def borrower_params
    params.require(:borrower).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :nmf, :description, :amnt_needed, :amnt_raised)
end 
 end
```

And **Borrowers**  Model

```
class Borrower < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :lenders, through: :transactions
has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy
# attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)\z/i

validates :first_name,    :presence   => true,
        :length               => { :maximum => 30 }

validates :last_name,    :presence   => true,
        :length               => { :maximum => 30 }

validates :email,   :presence   => true,
        :format               => { :with => email_regex },
        :uniqueness           => { :case_sensitive => false }
        #this validates the form input
# validates :password,  :presence => true
#before the user gets added to DB, run this function.
def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.password == submitted_password
end

def self.fetch_not_borrowers(lender_id, lender)
    return Borrower.find(:all, :conditions => ["borrowers.id NOT IN (?)", lender.borrower_ids])
    # return Borrower.find(:all, :conditions => ["lenders.id NOT IN (?)", lender.ids])
end

end
```

Comment: Model code for Borrower please?

Comment: I've added code for the Controller and Model, let me know if there is anything else you'd like.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but since your password is being stored in plain text, can I recommend an out of the box authentication solution like Devise? 

Try to setup a simple test case in the rails console. Set the password, then call some_user.valid? and inspect the user.errors hash. Check the user.changes after save as well. 

if there are no issues there, then you should review your development log, sometimes you might see an 'unpermitted params' message saying you are having issues with strong params in your updates.

Comment: Hmmm... password is not displayed because it never reaches the DB... Check the response to create...

Comment: @user2967130: I will make the switch to Devise eventually but as I'm still learning the ropes to Rails I wanted to see how I might manually create my registration.

Comment: @RubyRacer: The response is '[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.', but I've already set that particular value to false. Going to look more at this message.

Comment: @RubyRacer: Alright, I tried restarting my console first then changing that particular boolean to false and now the password is adding. Thanks for the help.